# Nougat notification bar limited to three icons?

Tags: notifications, 7.0-nougat, notification-bar, notification-icons

I had Marshmallow on my Samsung S6 before, and I would sometimes have many, *many* notifications - all the way to the system icons on the right.

Now I have Nougat on the phone, and it invariably shows a maximum of just *three* icons plus an ellipsis (...) to indicate that there are more. Of course the hidden notifications are the ones I am really interested in; the others are more or less static based on running background apps.

- Is there a way to adjust the limit of how many notifications are shown?
- Is this a Nougat "feature", or a Samsung "feature"?
- Is this specific to only some Samsung regions?

The notification LED seems to work as usual, so there's that.

<sup>I use "DRE" for my SM-G920F but I'm aware there are other regions that would also work on this phone. They probably all have various combinations of bloatware; if only I could find a bloatless version...</sup>

Answer (score 1):

you can limit the Galaxy to only show the last three notifications in the status  bar to keeps things clean and orderly. Head into Settings > Display > Status Bar and make any necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't confirm that this is Samsung-exclusive, I've got my phone showing 5 notifications right now in the status bar (OnePlus 5, Oxygen OS (Nougat, stock, very close to AOSP).
I don't know if there is a way to change this on our phone, but usually static notifications are given a very low priority, and are so shown last. Those apps may have a setting that can be changed in their settings section. Alternatively, you may be able to set an app to only be able to create low-priority notifications. I'm not sure how this will impact the functionality, so you would have to give it a try, but it may work for you.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for at least confirming that the limit of 3 is not Nougat itself. As for the notification priority, I don't see a way for a user to modify them. These are various notifications across all of my installed apps, not some I have created myself.

Comment: I've taken a couple [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/XoTWO) of that I mean by setting an app to only have low priority notifications. I got to the first screenshot by sliding the notification sideways, but not enough to remove it.

Comment: Cool, thank you! Is that a new feature in Nougat? ... Argh oh no, Samsung has meddled with it, it looks different for me and I can only choose whether or not to show it on the lock screen, and whether or not to "set as priority" so it shows even during "do not disturb". Damn you Samsung...